# One subtree of a connected graph can be extended by another subtree

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Recently I've been doing the following problem in graph theory:
Take $G$ to be a connected graph and $H_1$, $H_2$ are two acyclic subgraphs of $G$ with $V(H_1) = V(G)$, $V(H_2) = V(G)$ and $\lvert E(H_1) \rvert < \lvert E(H_2) \rvert$. Show that there exists $e \in E(H_2)-E(H_1)$ such that $H_1 + e$ is still acyclic.

Here is my original thought: By Kruskal's Algorithm, if we give a weight on every edge of $G$ by 1, then the algorithm will always return a minimum spanning tree of $G$, hence also a spanning tree. Notice that $H_1$ is acyclic, it can be seen as some intermediate steps of the algorithm, and thus there is a spanning tree $T$ of $G$ that contains $H_1$ as a subgraph. Now we can divide it into many cases:

1. If $H_2$ is also a subgraph of $T$, then by $H_2$ contains more edges than $H_1$, adding any extra edge of $H_2$ still makes $H_1$ acyclic.
2. If $H_2$ is not a subgraph of $T$ but intersects $T$ for some edges and no intersection of edges with $H_1$, then similar as case1, we pick an edge in the intersection.
3. If $H_2$ is not a subgraph of $T$ but intersects $T$ for some edges and those edges are in $H_1$, I'm trying to argue by contradiction. If $\forall e_i \in E(H_2)-E(H_1)$, $H_1+e_i$ contains a cycle $C_i$, then $C_i$ is also a unique cycle in $T+e_i$. I'm trying to argue that for each such $e_i \in E(H_2)-E(H_1)$, we can find distinct $\tilde{e_i} \in E(H_1)$ that is also contained in the unique cycle $C_i$. By this we can know that $\lvert E(H_1) \rvert \geq \lvert E(H_2) \rvert$, a contradiction. However, I got stuck at the last step of this case.

4.If $H_2$ is not a subgraph of $T$ at all, then we can apply the arguments in case3 to derive a contradiction.

Is my argument correct? Any hints will be thankful!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can simplify this somewhat. First assume that $H_2$ has the maximal possible number of edges and hence is a spanning tree. $H_1$ has less edges and is therefore disconnected. Consider two connected components of $H_1$, then $H_2$ needs to contain a path that connects these two components because it is a spanning tree. This path contains at least one edge that can be added to $H_1$ without creating a cycle.

If $H_2$ has less edges it is also disconnected. As $H_1$ has strictly less edges that $H_2$ there needs to be a connected component of $H_2$ such that $H_1$ restricted to that component has less edges than this component of $H_2$. Then you can apply the argument in the first paragraph to this component.